# How Bypass login in Kibana dashboard inside Iframe

Tags: angular, authentication, elasticsearch, iframe, kibana

How we pass authentication header in Iframe (Angular 8 ) of kibana dashboard?

Frontend: Angular 8
Kibana 7.7

Got html page of browser not support message.

Comment: Did you get the solution? Where you able to figure out?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure whether you need it to authenticate using the login details for your angular app but if it's for read only access to a dashboard then you can use 2 Nginx reverse proxies to auth against kibana using a pre-created read only user. Using the reverse proxies you can pass the auth details to kibana and make the iframe look like it requires no sign in.

- Firstly, you need to ensure that your dashboard cannot be edited by anyone viewing it via the IFrame. Add a kibana role which only has read privilege to the dashboard index. Create a user and give it that role.
- Send the Iframe to the first proxy

```sh
<iframe src="https://proxy1.my-domain.org" width="100%" height="5000"></iframe>
```

- The first proxy adds the kibana dashboard Iframe parameters and redirects to the second proxy

```sh
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/key-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/private-key.key;
    server_name proxy1.my-domain.org;

    location / {
            rewrite / https://proxy2.my-domain.org/app/dashboards#/view/933b84a0-6645-11eb-9acd-af0231282a2d?embed=true&_g=(filters:!(),refreshInterval:(pause:!t,value:0),time:(from:now-15m,to:now)) redirect;
    }

}
```

- The second proxy adds the Base64 encoded kibana login details and redirects to the actual kibana dashboard location.

```sh
echo -n my-user-name:my-password | base64
bXktdXNlci1uYW1lOm15LXBhc3N3b3Jk
```

```sh
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/key-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/private-key.key;
    server_name proxy2.my-domain.org;

    location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic bXktdXNlci1uYW1lOm15LXBhc3N3b3Jk"; # Base64 encoded username:password
            proxy_pass https://actual-kibana-server.somewhere.org:9243;
    }

}
```

It does look a bit like magic but we've got this working in production websites. I guess it would be possible to use a single Nginx setup but I've never tried it.

Comment: What if someone accesses the url of the first proxy (https://proxy1.my-domain.org)?  It opens kibana with logged in user (my-user-name) that can see all reports. Is that right?

Comment: Going to the first proxy would just send them to the next proxy with whatever user credentials you have added in the proxy settings. You should only use this with a read only user not with your own full access credentials.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to bypass the Kibana login whether be it within an iframe or not. If it was possible, that would be a big security loophole.